# How to clean a pull-request before merging?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have a question related to the pull-request mechanism on GitHub.

Bob commits some changes in its branch:

```
* Added feature foo 
* Added feature bar 
* Removed latency in baz
```

Then he creates a PR. Alice and other people refuse the PR and ask for changes. Bob adds new commits

```
* !fixup Added feature foo 
* !fixup Added feature bar 
* cosmetic change
```

Again they are not happy and they ask for more changes, so Bob gets angry

```
* Again some change, please accept my PR 
* Damned, I forgot this...
```

At the end we have something that everybody agrees with, but we have noisy commits. So three options remains:

1. We accept the PR but it gets ugly with all those commits
2. Bob `rebase -i` and `push -f --force-with-lease` (but what happens to the PR?)
3. Bob closes the PR, `rebase -i` on a new branch then creates a new PR.

What is the best option?

P.S. The `squash` is not an option since we want to `rebase` the pull-request and keep the initial three commits that features `foo`, `bar` and the latency issue fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **second option** looks fine. The pull request will be updated with the new commits from the `rebase -i` operation, replacing the previous commits. These new commits will appear after the last comment on the pull request, which lets reviewers know that there are new commits to review (to at least check that it's the same content as before).